# Why a specified chart is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I want to show that the set $M=\{(x^2,y^2,z^2,xy,xz,yz): (x,y,z)\in S^2\}$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $2$ **by explicitly constructing a smooth atlas**. My book proceeds as follows (with paraphrasing and different notation):

Using the real projective plane $S^2/\{p,-p\}$, we would arrive at such a chart for $M$ as $$\Phi:\mathbb D^2\to M$$ $$(x,y)\mapsto (x^2,y^2,1-x^2-y^2, xy,xz,yz),$$ where $\mathbb D^2$ is the open unit disk.

This is clearly a smooth map. But its inverse (which equals $(m_1,m_2,...,m_6)\mapsto (\sqrt m_1, \sqrt m_2)$) is not smooth. So I think this does not really define a chart. Are there any missing points?

Comment: There's something wrong with your map.  You say that $(x,y)$ maps to a quantity that also has expressions in terms of $z$, but do you mean to take $z = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ or is it some other quantity?

Comment: Yes I implicitly meant z denotes that expression. @Mnifldz

Comment: If you follow this approach, aren't you just going to end up computing in local coordinates that the map $S^2 \to M$ is a smooth imbedding?

Comment: I want to explicitly construct a smooth atlas on the “set“ $M$. I clarified my question. @Neal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the first four coordinates of the mapping give a $4$-to-$1$ mapping near the origin. We have to use the last two coordinates to get a $1$-to-$1$ mapping. In particular, the inverse function theorem tells us that
$$\phi(x,y) = \big(x\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2},y\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\big) = (v,w)$$
has a smooth inverse in a neighborhood of the origin, even if we cannot write down the explicit formula. Then you get a local smooth inverse of your mapping by taking $\phi^{-1}\circ\pi$, where $\pi$ is projection onto the last two coordinates. Both these maps are smooth.

Comment: I was trying to find an explicit smooth inverse around the origin whose restriction on $M$ would equal the square root map and it led me to this problem. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I apologize for my previous comment. I totally missed the point. But, in fact, your problem was not just with square roots. I believe that what you were focusing on was the issue I raised with the mapping being 4-to-1 in those first coordinates. (Now that you edited to include your thoughts, note that is not at all an inverse.) Interesting problem!

Comment: Yes exactly, I included my wrong thought so that my source of confusion which was not paying attention to the last coordinations gets more clear